# Hawking Radiation specific clarification

Tags: black-holes, antimatter, hawking-radiation, virtual-particles

If virtual particles on the edge of a black hole pop into existence randomly, wouldnt the likelyhood of a antiparticle generating on the inside of the black hole equal to a particle doing the same? So how is hawking radiation possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are (classically) absolutely correct. We can think of the particle-antiparticle pair of having an [equal probability for the two configurations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation) (AP inside, P outside vs P inside, AP outside). However, Hawking radiation is not preferential--only *one* of the particles needs to escape for the black hole to [lose mass and energy](https://www.physicsoftheuniverse.com/topics_blackholes_theory.html). It doesn't matter which particle gets the lucky break--only that one of the pair does.

Eventually, if this happens enough over a sufficiently [long period of time](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/BlackHoles/hawking.html), the black hole will have no mass left, a process called [*black hole evaporation*](https://medium.com/starts-with-a-bang/how-do-black-holes-evaporate-5463dbda6832).